# Не компилирует Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack4

Webpack 4 перестал компилировать
Вот выдает ошибку

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.168.0.101:8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1253:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1451:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1297:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpack-template@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --devtool source-map --output-pathinfo`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-template@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serj/.npm/_logs/2019-06-22T08_38_03_237Z-debug.log

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменял адрес сервера в конфигурационном файлике и все заработало

```
// Server
    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
        publicPath: "/",
        host: '192.168.0.102',
        port: '8081'
    },
```